# Android Threshold image processing

Tags: android, opencv, camera, threshold

Here I have a code (algorithm) using openCV for improving the image of a green board (that we use in schools) filtering the noise and changing the polarity in yellow and black.
and I need to implement on opencv4android  for real-time rendering using the camera.

**[image: Orginal]Orginal:**

**Threshold:[image]**

```
    int x,y; // variables to be used for thresholding

    int a=0;         // variables to be used in loop
    int count=0;     // variables to be used in loop



    //Step: 1 SImple brightness and contrast control using alpha and beta variables
    for( int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++ )
      { for( int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++ )
          { for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
              {
                       image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[c]                            saturate_cast<uchar>( alpha*( image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[c] ) + beta );
               }
           }
      }

    // Step: 3 calculating the threshold value using gray scale image
     for( x = 0; x < gray_image.rows; x++ )
     {
       for ( y = 0; y < gray_image.cols; y++ )
       {

        a=a+gray_image.at<uchar>(x,y);
        count=count+1;
       }
     }
     int thresh=0;;
     thresh=a/count;
      printf("%d",thresh); // Calculated the threshold of our image

    // Step:3 Applying the thresholding operation to our image
    for( x = 0; x < image.rows; x++ )
     {
       for ( y = 0; y < image.cols; y++ )
       {
             if(gray_image.at<uchar>(x,y)<thresh)

                      {image.at<cv::Vec3b>(x,y)[0] = 235;  // 0 element is for B component , 1 is for Green component, 2 is for Red component as in openCV BGR is the standard
                       image.at<cv::Vec3b>(x,y)[1] =206;  
                       image.at<cv::Vec3b>(x,y)[2] = 135; } //  below threshold value pixels are assigned whatever colour you decide 
             else


                    {image.at<cv::Vec3b>(x,y)[0] = 0;  
                     image.at<cv::Vec3b>(x,y)[1] = 0;  
                     image.at<cv::Vec3b>(x,y)[2] = 0; }    // above threshold value pixels are assigned this colour
        }
     }


    cv::namedWindow("Final threshold");
    cv::imshow("Final threshold",image);
    imwrite("F:\Threshold image.jpg",image); // saved the image to F drive with name Threshold Image

    waitKey(100);
```

Comment: Have you checked out OpenCV4Android ?

Comment: ya the code is different for implementing in android that's why i am ask your help what should be the changes when implementing it in opencv4android .

Comment: first, get rid of all those loops. there's a builtin function to find the mean() for an image, also a threshold() function, all available from [java](http://docs.opencv.org/java/).

Comment: what about displaying the threshold in yellow and black ?(default is black and white)

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#setTo(org.opencv.core.Scalar,%20org.opencv.core.Mat) - like `rgb.setTo(new Scalar(253,206,135), mask_from_threshold)`

Comment: This is my code .how do to i improve it ,the frames at which it process is slow    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(inputFrame.gray(), mIntermediateMat, new Size(11,11), 0);    Core.bitwise_not(mIntermediateMat, mIntermediateMat);    Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_DILATE, new Size(3,3), new Point(1,1));    Imgproc.dilate(mIntermediateMat, mIntermediateMat, kernel);    Imgproc.threshold(mIntermediateMat, mIntermediateMat, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);    mIntermediateMat.setTo(new Scalar(253,206,135));